# Why are Leicester & co pronounced as they are?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, history, pronunciation-vs-spelling

What is the origin of the pronunciation of words like *Leicester, Gloucester, Worcestershire*? Presumably, the spelling predates the pronunciation but what is the history here? What language do the words originate from?

Is this just simple elision or is there a more specific, shared origin of these words and the process that changed them?

Comment: It might be interesting to contrast the Lancaster set with the Manchester set with the Leicester set.

Comment: Actually, these are evidence that the *spelling* predates the *pronunciation*. I.e. when the spelling of these placenames became fossilized, they were pronounced with many more syllables than people give them nowadays.

Comment: And, conversely, why is Cirencester pronounced siren-sester and are there any other exceptions to the "rule" that -cester is pronounced "stuh".

Comment: @David: I don't believe it 8is (by the locals); more like "Sissester".

Comment: @TimLymington [Wikipedia disagrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cirencester#Pronunciation), though without citation. But even "Sissester" would go against the pattern of all the other -cesters, which would suggest "Sirenster".

Comment: Then there is Leominster, pronounced *Le'm'ster*

Comment: When I lived in Boston, I heard it pronounced, "*L'MINster*"

Comment: @Marthaª fair enough, question edited.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

These are all quite old names with many syllables—an ideal place for ellipsis, elision, and contraction.

The *-cester* bit is from the Old English word *ceaster*, which in itself is borrowed from Latin *castrum*. It is thus cognate to *castle*. (The palatalisation of the initial /k/ to /tʃ/ is common in Old English and was more widespread in some dialects than in others, so at some point, there were probably two variants around: *caster* /kastər/ and *ceaster* /tʃastər/.)

In Old English, *ceaster* referred to a Roman town or settlement (in England). As tchrist notes in his comment, some other places that have this element in their names include *Lancaster*, *Doncaster*, and *Manchester*.

The first part of names that have *-cester* tend to be inherited place names of either Anglo-Saxon or (even earlier) British Celtic stock, often names of rivers or other local toponyms.

Going from Old English down through the centuries, the cities the first element of whose names ended in a consonant (like *Lan-*, *Don-*, *Man-*) usually kept a fuller version of the word *ceaster*, retaining the initial consonant. The ones whose first element ended in a vowel, on the other hand, ended up having the initial /tʃ/ (or /k/, as in *Lancaster* and *Doncaster*) in an intravocalic position, where it was quite likely to be weakened—something that happens often in place names, especially longer ones.

Thus, *Leicester* and *Gloucester* were once pronounced as they’re written, with a /tʃ/ (or perhaps /k/); but that consonant was weakened over time and eventually disappeared altogether, leaving the vowels free to contract into single monophthongs, too.

Comment: It's interesting that the place names would derive from Roman camps (which even in temporary use tended to be very well-constructed), and today in the United States there are many cities which grew up around permanent military posts, many of which no longer feature the posts, but the names persist: Fort Wayne (Indiana); Fort Worth (Texas); Fort Collins (Colorado); and many more.

Comment: And then there’s *Legeceasterscir* > *Cestrescir* > *Cheshire* > *kitty-grin* :).

Comment: Want to pop some comment on "Chichester" in? Unless some other development is already "invisible", one would have thought it should have resulted in \*Cicester pronounced *sister*!

Comment: @Davïd _Chichester_ is probably from _Cissa_ + _ceaster_, which is slightly different again: here we have before _ceaster_ a non-initial, unstressed syllable (probably a schwa), which apparently got syncopated out before the weakening of the intervocalic took place. That left _Cissceaster_, which was then simplified to just _Ciceaster_, now spelt _Chichester_. At least that would be my guess at the chronology. (Incidentally, ‘sister’ is an attested and occasionally used contracted pronunciation, but of Cirencester.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet *leaving the vowels free to contract into single monopthongs*. Isn't the freaky thing about *Leicester* etc meant to be that that vowel/syllable has disappeared altogether? /lestə/ for example. Or have I got the wrong vowel there? (quite possible)

Comment: @Araucaria Well, the di- or triphthong (whatever it may have been exactly) was definitely contracted into a single monophthong /e/. The originally disyllabic sequence was indeed reduced by one syllable, but I'd just consider that part of the contraction.

Comment: /tʃ/ is neither a palatle consonant nor a palatilized consonant, strictly speaking. The claim that /tʃ/ would be likely to lenite in certain positions. Way I see it, the answer amounts to an educated guess. What's the indication for /k/ > /tʃ/, if we hear no trace of it today? Much rather I expect /tʃ/ is the modern realization of something else, not even the phone in the "Leicester" of old. An answer that leaves me guessing is not a good one.

Comment: @vectory Palatalisation is the standard name of the process which turned PG _*k_ into OE /tʃ/ before front vowels. It doesn’t matter that the resulting sound is not strictly palatal; it remains the name of the process. I have no idea what you mean by “hear no trace of it today”. It’s a _diachronic_ change, so obviously we can only hear one stage at any synchronic point in time. It is, however, one of the most basic and easily-proven sound changes that occurred in/before OE, which hundreds of examples, many even within derivations from the same roots (e.g., _drink_ vs _drench_).

Answer (score 17):

The *cester/chester* ending can be traced back to the Roman occupation: *castra* is Latin for camp, so these placenames indicate Roman army encampments (or more likely permanent garrisons, given the names' persistence).

The [Grammarphobia](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2012/05/worcester-source.html) blog gives a good run down of the evidence which traces these pronunciations through history; the scansion in Shakespeare, for example, suggests that the elision was in common use in his time. The article also speculates on why the pronunciation and spelling are so divergent: perhaps because the people writing down the placenames (the literate scribes of Domesday Book; the monarch's tax-collectors &c) weren't the ones living there, coupled with the usual spelling free-for-all that only started to be regularised with mass-printing.

Sometimes pronunciation can swing back into line with spelling; while Cirencester is now generally pronounced as spelled, it had been elided to [*cicester*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cirencester#Pronunciation).

Similar elisions are common in other patterns of placenames (Kirkby:*kirby*; Kircudbright:*Kurkoobree*; Marylebone:*marleybone/mairbun/m'bn*) and so probably represent a universal trend towards elision in familiar and locally-shared placenames.

The relative lack of shortening in such names as Manchester, Lancaster, Chichester, Colchester looks to be caused by the middle consonant 'catching' the speaker and preventing further elision. The examples in the question, by contrast, don't have a strong middle consonant.

Comment: Oh, dear, I knew I should have waited to see if @Janus Bahs Jacquet was going to post...

Comment: And then there's "[Milngavie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milngavie)"!

Comment: @Flaneurban Our answers compliment each other nicely (and I've upvoted yours)—plus I think you actually finished yours before I got mine in, by about a minute or so. (Currently on mobile device, so can't check time stamps, but I seem to recall the “A new answer has been posted” bar while typing.)

Comment: I'll certainly be upping my game in future; currently researching IPA shortcuts

Comment: +1 Your post was good too, perhaps better in that it addresses the dropping or otherwise of the middle vowel, which after all is what freaks people out about the examples! Re IPA, I use the site I've linked below. It's great. Can use keyboard + shift of click on symbols (keyboard + Shift goes on what the symbol *looks* like - not sound). Can cut n paste into here or word docs etc. Really useful [Type IPA](http://ipa.typeit.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I would consider my answer personal observation due to a software project. I believe it is a general trend. It would be helpful, if people would offer corrections to my observation.

Human attention span seems to constrain a concept to be pronounced no longer than 3 syllables. This human tendency is due to the angst of wanting to say as much as possible within a given time.

I can say this about English and Hebrew, since these are the languages I am familiar with. Perhaps someone could verify that French, Chinese, Hausa, Japanese, etc succumb to the same constraint.

In standard British English, three syllable words are often contracted to two-syllables during pronunciation. If that is not possible or inconvenient, then words are normally contracted to 2.5 syllables.

In standard British English pronunciation, a word usually has 2 major syllables and 1 minor syllable = 2.5 syllables. Another frequent pattern is two major and two minor syllables = 2 + 0.5 + 0.5 = 3.

These are the most common patterns of pronunciation (M=major, m = minor syllable) for three syllable words.

1. M-m-M
2. m-M-M
3. m-M-m-M
4. M---M

Frequently, pattern #2 is contracted to pattern #4.

For those rare words, or chemical names, a word is broken up into groups where the pronunciation of a group conforms to the above patterns.

There also is the principle of **emphasis on the first syllable**, so that a word is pronounced

```
m1-M2-M3
```

in order for the pronunciation of m1 to be sufficiently diminished to allow M2 to effectively be the first syllable. That is, at all times emphasize the pronunciation of the 1st syllable - but if that sounds silly, suppress the 1st syllable to allow the 2nd Syllable the prominence of a 1st syllable. (Beyond the scope of this question, I have developed a syllable valency rating which documents what syllables get to be suppressed - such that the lower the valency, the higher its "risk" of being suppressed.)

Examples:

- Normally => M-m-M => M---M (NORM'ly)
- Leicester => M-m-M => M---M (LE'Ster)
- Gloucester => M-m-M => M---M (GLO'Ster)
- Worcester => M-m-M => M---M (WOOR'Ster) => (WOO'Ster)
- Elucidate => m-M-m-M => m-M---M (eLiUS'sdate)
- Empowerment => m-M-m-M  => m-M---M ('mPOW'rment)
- Montgomery => m-M-m-M  => m-M---M (m'GUM'mry)
- Government => M-m-M  => M---M (GOV'ment)

Compare the contraction of *Government* to common Indian English
Government => M-m-M  => M---M (GOU'ment)

#### Worcestershire

- Worcester shire => M-m-M M-m => M---M (WOO'Ster) M---(SHier)
  => M---m-M--- (WOO'ste'SHier)

Another phenomenon is the metathesis of multiple single syllable words into one word group to be pronounced as if they were a single word conforming to the three syllable patterns.

- Don't {Eat it up} => Don't {M-m-M EAT'iTUP}

Other forms of contractions are having

- T pronounced as a click. e.g. Often => Of^n, Bottle => Bot^l
- D smoothened to J (graduate => gra juate, procedure)
- T smoothened to Ch (virtual)

OTOH, there is the reverse-contraction phenomenon, which is rare in British English but of which Americans are excessively guilty. The extension of 2 syllable words to 2.5 or 3 syllables

- Emty => Empty (England)
- Coupon => KiUpon (US)
- Figure => Figear (US)
- Nuclear => NOO-kiu-lear (GWB)

Comment: German agglutinates like crazy and does not follow your rule.  On the other hand, what on earth does this have to do with the Question?  BG, I mean no offense, but this "answer" is more a blog post than a StackExchange participation.

Comment: I don't buy your three syllable limitation. There are _many_ words with more than 3 syllables. The rest is quite interesting but I was more interested in the specific history of those words.

Comment: "There are many words with more than 3 syllables" - as I stated, such words are broken into groups, where the pronunciation of each group conforms to the three syllable patterns.

Comment: I don't think the downvotes are deserved, but putting your motivation of a software project plus a lot of general stuff was an initial turnoff. You might be better off posting your own question to get answers for the general phenomenon of contraction, and reference that with a shorter answer that's more specific to the place names here.

Comment: @BlessedGeek: if you ever did post a question of your own, could you provide the link here in the comments or in your answer?  (just upvoted)...

Answer (score -1):

So yes, in Shakespeare's First Folio, you'll see the spelling "Gloster"...

...but I just figured that if you organize the letters into syllables differently, then each word is indeed spelled just as it is pronounced.

Leice|ster

Glouce|ster

Worce|ster|shire

I might even speculate that "Manchester" is actually being pronounced Manche|ster, because if you try to say "Manche" followed by "ster", the reduced "e" automatically inserts itself... and generally, when I hear Brits pronounce the name, I hear that the e is indeed reduced. [EDIT:  Likewise Chiche|ster.]

Comment: So, what you're saying is that if you keep the pronunciation as it it and break the word into syllables, then it's pronounced as it's spelled. Well, yes, obviously. That's 'cause you assume the pronunciation. For _Worcestershire_, for example, you seem to be pronouncing _Worce_ as _wus_, and _shire_ silent. Neither of these would be pronounced that way in other contexts so I don't see what point you're making.